# How to add limited number of posts programmatically in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

My requirement is ::
create a category for backup of few number of posts (say 10 posts), I need to save only that number of latest posts.

I have used following code to create post:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => $tweet_time,
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(9)
    );
$postid=wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Check the number of posts in the category before inserting any post.

```
$args = array(
    'include'                  => '9',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
    'pad_counts'               => true 
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
if($category[0]->count < 10){
    // Your Code Goes Here
}
```